# Single-user OpenID server with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, ruby-on-rails-3, openid-provider

My website's root page automatically redirects all users to some subpage via http header.

`http://example.com/ → http://example.com/subpage`

I want to use my domain `example.com` as OpenID. The problem is that I have to add some tag to my root page, but it should redirect all users on subpage. I can change the type of redirection and use e.g. meta tag. But is there a better way to implement that and don't break instant http redirect?

Maybe I can somehow distinguish OpenID request and only that time respond with html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the location of a [Yadis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yadis) document (which could be a static file in `public/`) by setting the `X-XRDS-Location` header, or you can choose to handle the `application/xrds+xml` MIME type at your application root dynamically.

- See the [Yadis wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yadis#Discovery_of_the_Yadis_Resource_Descriptor) for an overview of what the Yadis document is and what you need to return in your XRDS document.
- There's a [rubyonrails.org blog post](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/19/using-custom-mime-types) on how to handle a custom MIME type. It looks like this is still how it works in [Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/render-options-in-rails-3/) (you don't need a custom renderer).

Comment: I've added `XRDS` responder, that you can see at http://sema.in with `Accept: application/xrds+xml` header (I checked with htty gem), but I can't log in with this openid on any website. E.g. StackOverflow answers "No OpenID endpoint found."

Comment: It turned out that very few websites support this kind of openid. I've replaced the redirect with a page. Standard openid link tags work everywhere.